# Intrinsics SIMD instruction to replace values

Tags: c#, simd, intrinsics

I wonder how it would be possible to replace byte values in a `Vector128<byte>`

I think it is okay to assume the code below where we have a `resultvector` with
those values :
**<0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0>**

Here I like to create a new vector where all "0" will be replaced with "2"
and all "1" will be replaced with "0" like this :
**<2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2>**

I am not sure if there is an intrinsics for this or how to achieve this?

Thank you!

```
        //Create array
        byte[] array = new byte[16];
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { array[i] = 0; }
        for (int i = 4; i < 8; i++) { array[i] = 1; }
        for (int i = 8; i < 16; i++) { array[i] = 0; }


        fixed (byte* ptr = array)
        {
            byte* pointarray = &*((byte*)(ptr + 0)); 
            System.Runtime.Intrinsics.Vector128<byte> resultvector = System.Runtime.Intrinsics.X86.Avx.LoadVector128(&pointarray[0]);

            //<0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0>
            //resultvector
        }
```

Comment: Maybe something like `2-(resultvector<<1)` (if shifts are not possible, just add to itself). But how did you actually compute `resultvector`? (If you are able to modify that calculation, there could be more efficient ways).

Comment: I edited my post. I think that example is equal to how the real example is where I am left with this `resultvector`. I am not sure what this means: `2-(resultvector<<1)` ? I use C#.

Comment: `<<` is the shift operator. I'm not very familiar with C# so I don't know if it allows that on SIMD types (or if C# overloads operators for SIMD types ...). Essentially you need to calculate `2-(a[i]+a[i])` for each element (for which there must be a way with just two SIMD instructions).

Comment: You probably did not understand what I meant by "how you actually compute `resultvector`". If your code *was* how you actually calculate it, just replace `array[i]=0;` by `array[i]=2;` and `array[i]=1;` by `array[i]=0` (I'm sure this is not what you need ...).

Comment: Yes, I am not sure if  `<<` is possible to use. I have never seen that one to be used in C#. I think it is not possible. I beleive there must be some kind of SIMD instruction in C# to use somehow, I hope.

Comment: Then I see what you ment: `>> just replace array[i]=0; by array[i]=2;` That will not work I am afraid in my real code because there is a loop that increament values. So I only know After that loop. After the loop, I am left with the `resultvector` so nothing could be done before there.

Comment: SSE2 has SIMD shifts.  The syntax might not be `<<`, but @chtz is just describing what math needs to happen on each element using plain scalar C# syntax.  Another option is `(val^1) + 1`.  But both of those will take 2 instructions each, vs. a `pshufb` table lookup taking only 1 asm instruction; Soonts' idea looks good to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instruction for that is `pshufb`, available in modern .NET as [Avx2.Shuffle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.intrinsics.x86.avx2.shuffle?view=netcore-3.1#System_Runtime_Intrinsics_X86_Avx2_Shuffle_System_Runtime_Intrinsics_Vector256_System_Byte__System_Runtime_Intrinsics_Vector256_System_Byte__), and [Ssse3.Shuffle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.intrinsics.x86.ssse3.shuffle?view=netcore-3.1) for 16-byte version. Both are really fast, 1 cycle latency on modern CPUs.

Pass your source data into shuffle control mask argument, and a special value for the first argument which is the bytes being shuffled, something like this:

```
// Create AVX vector with all zeros except the first byte in each 16-byte lane which is 2
static Vector256<byte> makeShufflingVector()
{
    Vector128<byte> res = Vector128<byte>.Zero;
    res = Sse2.Insert( res.AsInt16(), 2, 0 ).AsByte();
    return Vector256.Create( res, res );
}
```

See `_mm_shuffle_epi8` section on page 18 of [this article](http://const.me/articles/simd/simd.pdf) for details.

**Update:** if you don’t have SSSE3, you can do the same in SSE2, in 2 instructions instead of 1:

```
static Vector128<byte> replaceZeros( Vector128<byte> src )
{
    src = Sse2.CompareEqual( src, Vector128<byte>.Zero );
    return Sse2.And( src, Vector128.Create( (byte)2 ) );
}
```

By the way, there’s a [performance problem](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/13811) in .NET that prevents compiler from loading constants outside of loops. If you gonna call that method in a loop and want to maximize the performance, consider passing both constant vectors, with zero and 2, as method parameters.

Comment: Thank you! I have a little problem to follow this exactly. I can't use `Vector256` on my CPU but I do have a `shuffle` method like this. But are not sure what I should put as a `mask` in the second argument? `System.Runtime.Intrinsics.X86.Avx.Shuffle(resultvector, Vector128<byte> mask)`

Comment: @Andreas If you don’t have AVX2, use the 16-byte version, `Ssse3.Shuffle`. The mask in the second argument is your source vector, with the byte values being either 0 or 1. The code will do this to each of your input byte: `( 0 == b ) ? 2 : 0`, because the shuffle source parameter is all zeroes except the first byte which is 2.

Comment: If you have AVX2 just can’t use Vector256.Create method, create the same value in some other way. You can load from 32-bytes long array of bytes, or better use stackalloc to avoid GC.

Comment: `Ssse3.Shuffle` and `Avx.Shuffle` are not supported by my platform when trying to run those. `Sse2.Shuffle(resultvector, Convert.ToByte(2))` is supported but the first argument can only take for example `int` and not `byte`. So it seems I can only run 4 instructions at a time? (Though I have not figured out how to use this yet)

Comment: @Andreas The 16-bytes version, from SSSE3 set, is supported by Intel starting from Core 2 Duo (2007), by AMD starting from Bobcat (2011). Are you sure you want to support CPUs older than that? Computers don’t usually live that long.

Comment: I have a `piledriver amd 6174` processor. I will only run this code on my computer. I have 64 cores of this processor. So I beleive I am stuck to write code for this processor?

Comment: @Andreas That one is from 2010, and you’re out of luck. You’ll have to do something else then, e.g. compare bytes with zeros with `Sse2.CompareEqual` instruction, then `Sse2.And` to get the values you need. By the way, according to cpubenchmark.net a modern $60 CPU, Ryzen 3 1200, is twice faster than Opteron 6174, despite it only has 4 cores versus 12.

Comment: Yes, I tried all possible `Shuffle` methods and only `Avx` seems to work but have no `byte` vectors. I tried to think about a way with `Sse2.CompareEqual` and `Sse2.And` but will try to see if that even is possible because I am trying to replace values, not add or sum them. Yes CPUs really got faster. Next computer I buy I need to think about the processors so they can use SIMD instructions the most efficient way.

Comment: That is great. Thank you that works to do it like that. I also found a very similar method by going back 2 steps in my original code and use `substract` in a special way. `passing both constant vectors, with zero and 2, as method parameters` that is true. I do that with all those types of vectors so they are already declared and only passed along. Thank you for all your help. It was really helpful!

Comment: @Soonts: suggestion: `(val^1) + 1` only needs one vector constant and has the same number of instructions.  (Still needs a `movdqa` to copy the constant, or a `movdqu` load and then destroying the loaded value).  `pcmpeqb` and `paddb` on K10 have the same performance of 2/clock.  (And so do boolean instructions like pand/pxor).